# Delete entire row based on part of the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have spreadsheets that list the dates in column A, ex 12/1/2016 1:45:00 AM. I reformat all the cells in this column so they display Day, Month #, Year. Example `Thursday, December 01, 2016`. The `Find` function works if I click on the actual find button and search for the values, however I am struggling to code this. I want to delete all the rows that contain "Saturday" and "Sunday". The latest code I have tried is as follows;

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "*Saturday*" Then
Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

I have also tried the following code as well;

```
Set Find = Range("A:A").Find("Saturday", LookIn:=xlValues)
Do Until Find Is Nothing
    Find.EntireRow.Delete
    Set Find = Range("A:A").FindNext
Loop
```

Comment: Use `Like`: `If (Cells(i, "D").Value) Like "*Saturday*" Then`

Answer (score 1):

Set the LookAt Parameter to `xlPart`

```
Find("Saturday", , , xlPart)
```

Comment: Ahhh - I had forgotten that `Find` "remembers" which parameters it last used.  So omitting the `LookAt:=xlPart` would work if the OP had previously done a manual `Find` like that, but wouldn't work if their previous find was for a `xlWhole`.  That explains why the OP's code worked for me.

Comment: yeah, this is one of the fun bits. :) Robust approach is to store your current settings, run the Find method and one you are done reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "*Saturday*" Then`
```

to

```
If (Cells(i, "D").Text) Like "*Saturday*" Then
```

Using `Text` instead of `Value` will access the displayed value, rather than the underlying value (which is a date), and using `Like` instead of `=` will allow wildcards to work.

---

Your question is confusing as to which column the dates are in.  Some of your code (and your question) suggests they are in column A, but other parts of your code suggest column D.  If they are in column A, change the code above to use `"A"` instead of `"D"`.